# Скрипт замены данных из списка

Tags: sql

Всем привет!
Имеется sql запрос, в рамках которого хотелось бы его размножить на все имеющиеся сервера.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(changecash) FROM consolidation.set000_cashpayment
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(changecash) FROM setretail.set000_cashpayment where id <= (select max(id) from consolidation.set000_cashpayment );
```

Хотелось бы увидеть его в таком формате:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(changecash) FROM consolidation.set000_cashpayment
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(changecash) FROM setretail.set000_cashpayment where id <= (select max(id) from consolidation.set000_cashpayment );

SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(changecash) FROM consolidation.set001_cashpayment
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(changecash) FROM setretail.set001_cashpayment where id <= (select max(id) from consolidation.set001_cashpayment );

SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(changecash) FROM consolidation.set002_cashpayment
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(changecash) FROM setretail.set002_cashpayment where id <= (select max(id) from consolidation.set002_cashpayment );
```

Причем нумерация в моем случае идет от 000 до 019 с пропуском кодов 009,013.
Как это возможно реализовать без Ctrl + F и Ctrl + H
Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Хранимая процедура с динамическим SQL.

Comment: clickhouse не поддерживает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю почему модераторы убрали все теги, кроме SQL, админ им судья.

Проблему решил написанием скрипта autohotkey. Выделяем текст со значениями 001 и нажимаем ALT+1, получаем размноженную строчку с исключениями 9, 13 магазинов.

```
!1::
adress := A_Temp "\Loop.txt"
Send ^c
file := FileOpen(adress, "w")
Loop
{
    if a_index > 19
        break  ; Terminate the loop
    else if a_index = 9
        continue ; Skip the below and start a new iteration
    else if a_index = 13
        continue ; Skip the below and start a new iteration
    else 
    {
        if a_index < 10
        {
            NewStr := StrReplace(Clipboard, "001", 00 . a_index)
        }
        else
        {
            NewStr := StrReplace(Clipboard, "001", 0 . a_index)
        }
        file.WriteLine(NewStr)
    }
}
file.Close()

file := FileOpen(adress, "r")
TestString := file.Read()
file.Close()

FileDelete, adress

Clipboard := TestString 
Send ^v

Return
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать выборку из [sys.objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), добавив фильтр по имени `like 'set[0-9][0-9][0-9]_cashpayment'`, и вы получите список нужных таблиц. Далее на его основе строить динамический запрос.

Comment: Это если у него SQL Server - что не факт...